# Is it possible to check the progress of of a currently running clamAV scan?

Tags: anti-virus, malware, clamav

I have searched around but not found a possible solution to this so far.
I have an ongoing scan which I thought would've been finished at certain time, but unfortunately it has not. So I am wondering if there's a way to check the scan progress of this ongoing progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAICT, this is not possible—you can either have all scanned files printed to the console, or just print infected files. Then at the end, ClamAV will print a summary. I haven't been able to find a way to get any ongoing statistics.

The only way I could imagine hacking it to do this would be:

1. First, count all files recursively in the directory(ies) that will be scanned by ClamAV, then store that number in a variable.
2. Run ClamAV wrapped in a script that counts the lines output, and compares that to the count from step 1.

I tried doing this quickly one time, but couldn't get it working well enough for an automated Jenkins job I set up... so I eventually gave up on it. Sorry :(

Comment: It's surprising and annoying that they don't include that sort of functionality with clamscan.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old, answered thread but I wanted to try geerlingguy's idea (whom I am a fan :-)) and in case others end up here provide a codified solution.

If you want to scan the folder *foo* for example, you start the scan with:

```
clamscan -r foo | tee /tmp/scan.log
```

or

```
clamscan -r foo > /tmp/scan.log
```

You can then run the following script with the arguments of the folder being scanned and the log file, in this example

```
status.sh foo /tmp/scan.log
```

Where the contents of the status.sh file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
folder=$1
log=$2
numFiles=`find $folder -type f | wc -l` 
echo $numFiles files to be processed

numProcessed=`wc -l $log | awk '{print $1'}`
percent=`echo "scale=2;$numProcessed*100./$numFiles." | bc`
echo $percent percent complete.
```

One could combine running of the scan and checking the status into a single script if needed.

Answer (score 1):

While this is an old thread I still wanted to share my solution using *pipeviewer* (pv) here:

```
dir="./Downloads"; clamscan --recursive $dir | pv --line-mode -s $(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l) > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the `-i` option (Only print infected files.) of clamscan, so I get output only when an infected file is found.

For checking on which file clamscan is currently working, you can use:

```
lsof -a -d 0-999 -c clamscan /
```

The lsof options have been taken from https://serverfault.com/a/106408/508349